# What would be the best way to install (distribute) dynamic libraries in Mac OSX using CMake/Cpack?

Tags: macos, cmake

I have a project whose artifacts are two dynamic libraries, let's say `libX.dylib` and `libY.dylib` (or `.so` for linux distributions). There are no executables.

Now I would like to distribute these libraries. Since I already use CMake to compile it, I looked at CPack and successfully generated `.tgz`  and `.deb` packages for Linux. However, for Mac OSX I have no idea and the CPack Wiki about its [generators](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators) did not help me much. I managed to generate a PackageMaker package, but as clearly stated at [this packagemaker howto](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Stuff/PackageMaker_Howto.html), there is no uninstall option when using this util. I then read a bit about [Bundles](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/corefoundation/conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html), but I feel lost specially since I have no executable.

**Question:** What is the correct way to generate a package for Mac OSX using CPack?

My ideal scenario would be either something that installs as easily as a bundle or as a deb file in debian/ubuntu.

Thanks for your help

**Edit**
One more detail: the code to one of these libraries is not open, so I can't expect the users to do a `cmake; make; make install`

That's why I want a .deb, .tar.gz, bundle or whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to install it the UNIX-y way (which is totally an ok thing to do, and actually my own preference as a Mac user) or if you want to install it as a Mac OS X Framework.

To install the libraries the UNIX-y way, you can use:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS target1 target2 DESTINATION lib)
```

In the above, replace `target1` and `target2` with the names of the targets that resulted in libX.dylib and libY.dylib being generated (i.e. whatever you used in ADD_LIBRARY). You can use the variable `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` in order to determine where the library ultimately ends up... with the above, if you set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `/usr/local`, then it will install the libraries in `/usr/local/lib`

**Edit**
Based on your update, you may find [Component Install with CPack](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:Component_Install_With_CPack) and [CPack Mac OS X PackageMaker Generator](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators#PackageMaker_.28OSX_only.29) to be of interest. Since you will be installing libraries into the system, the PackageMaker generator is the one you should use. If you were merely distributing an application, then creating a ".app" bundle and distributing it in a ".dmg" would be the proper thing to do. PackageMaker is installed on Mac OS X when you install the Xcode Developer Tools. To package a ".app" bundle in a ".dmg", you can use the Mac OS X disk utility application or its associated commandline tools.

Comment: Actually, it's difficult to express myself in this situation. I am more interested in the distribution of the libraries. For example, for debian/ubuntu, I use a .deb generated by CMake/CPack (therefore I already use `INSTALL`), but I don't know what to do it in mac.

Comment: Cool I didn't know the component install feature. Also, you are right, the packagemaker it's the way to go with libraries, as explained in http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/distributing/distibuting.html ( I just found the link )... unfortunately, the uninstall option is still a wish

Comment: What is the difference between the CPack DragnDrop and CPack Bundle generators? (assuming my application does need dylibs, but also contains an executable, gresources, icons and more..)